# Runtime Attribute of UITextFiled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have so many UITextField in my App.

I don't want to allow user to enter special characters those textfields.

I know, I can use **shouldChangeCharactersInRange** delegate method of UITextFiled and validate it, But this approach is feasible for 5-8 UITextFiled not for 15-20.

I want to validate those(15-20) **UITextFileds** using **RuntimeAttributes** and **UICategory** as below links:-

http://johannesluderschmidt.de/category-for-setting-maximum-length-of-text-in-uitextfields-on-ios-using-objective-c/3209/

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/05/30/xcode-runtime-attributes/

I tried and create UICategory of UITextFiled as below:-

**UITextField+RunTimeExtension.h**

```
@interface UITextField (RunTimeExtension)

@property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL *isAllowedSpecialCharacters;

@end
```

**UITextField+RunTimeExtension.m**

```
-(void)setIsAllowedSpecialCharacters:(BOOL *)isAllowedSpecialCharacters{

-(BOOL)isIsAllowedSpecialCharacters{
    if(self.isAllowedSpecialCharacters){
        NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];

        NSString *filtered = [[self.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet]  componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        return [self.text isEqualToString:filtered] || [self.text isEqualToString:@" "];
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

and add this attribute in RuntimeAttribute as below image:

[image: Runtime Attribute]

But didn't work, if this property is checked or not.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your code. See my answer for corrections.

**UITextField+SpecialCharacters.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITextField (SpecialCharacters)

@property(nonatomic,assign) NSNumber *allowSpecialCharacters;
//here you were using BOOL *

@end
```

**UITextField+SpecialCharacters.m**

```
#import "UITextField+SpecialCharacters.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UITextField (SpecialCharacters)

static void *specialCharKey;

-(void) setAllowSpecialCharacters:(NSNumber *)allowSpecialCharacters{

    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &specialCharKey, allowSpecialCharacters, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

}

-(NSNumber *) allowSpecialCharacters{

    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &specialCharKey);
}

@end
```

> Always set the names for getter and setter as per the standards.

In your ViewController, set delegate for textfield and implement following delegate method as per your requirement:

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([textField.allowSpecialCharacters boolValue]){
        NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];

        NSString *filtered = [[textField.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet]  componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        return [textField.text isEqualToString:filtered] || [textField.text isEqualToString:@" "];
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

In storyboard/nib, you should set runtime attribute as in snapshot. You can set value to 1 or 0 as per your requirement.

[image]

This is working fine at my side. Hope it solves your problem. Thanks.

Comment: What if i use shouldChangeCharactersInRange in category.?

Comment: It is a delegate method, not a method textfield inherits.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create custom textfield `MyCustomTextField extends UITextField` and use this custom textfield wherever needed?

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: No i don't want to use custom. I want to use RuntimeAttribute only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below custom class to meet all your requirements. It uses regular expressions to validate `textField` you can edit them to handle `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` according to your regular expression.

https://github.com/tomkowz/TSValidatedTextField